# HD 2500 graphics issues

Tags: graphics-card, integrated-graphics, transporting

I've recently moved my desktop PC and got a box with a loose CPU cooler and some other moved parts.  As I reattached the components, I'm seeing problems which seem to be isolated by my AMD HD6850.  I cannot boot in my windows install without the system going crazy about 3 minutes in... I think it isn't cooling enough anymore or something.

So, I'm trying to confirm by checking my system with my iGPU (HD2500 from a i7-2600K).

I cannot get it to boot in windows, so I decided to try it in Linux and see problems with the Xorg not working... "Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices."

I suspect that something is wrong with the drivers, but wondered if there are any particular suggestions and getting my system up and running.  At this point, I'm reasonably sure the video card requires replacement and am moving on that, but would welcome any advised actions. Thanks.

Comment: You said a loose CPU.... Did you reseat it properly and put new thermal paste on, and make sure the GPU is correctly seated? You can try cleaning the pins with some alcohol, but not a lot.